# Intuition behind division in permutation

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

So, I am trying to explain this concept but I would like also to understand why it’s true.We have m objects and n spaces where $m\leq n$,
what is the intuition behind the division between $n!$ and $(n-m)!$. I mean it works, considering two letters in four spaces we just need to multiply $4$ by $3$ and stop because there are no elements left, and algebraically this can be done also using the above formula, because common terms cancel out.But intuitively, why is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign $m$ objects to $m$ spaces, we first assign $n$ objects to $m$ spaces ($x$ possibilities) and then assign the remaining $n-m$ objects to the remaining $n-m$ spaces.
$$
m!=x\cdot (n-m)!
$$
So what is $x$?

Comment: I was asking for an intuition but try to tell me if this is good: We have 4 chairs and two children.The formula should be 4*3 or 4!/(4-2)!, in fact we lose 2 combinations for each possible arrangement of 4 children (if we used two more children we would have 4, positions child 1, times 3, position child 2, and now we  would have 2! positions child 3 and 4, which would be multiplied by 4*3 because we need to find combinations child 3/4 with child 1/2.Think this makes sense.

Comment: @AlexD'ago that is correct :)

Comment: Thanks Rezha :D

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a standard 52 card deck of cards and we want to draw 3 cards. There are 52 * 51 * 49 permutations of this. This is naturally $\frac {52!}{48!}$.  Ignoring suits for the moment, we draw a 10, J, 9. For **each** set of three cards, we have 3 * 2 * 1 or 3! possible arrangesments (ex. 10, 9, J; J 9 10; J 10 9 etc. etc.).

To neutralize the effects of **each** possible permutation, we would divide out the permutations. Therefore, we get $\frac {52!}{48!3!}$. Hope this helps!!

Comment: You meant to write $52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50$, with corresponding changes thereafter.